# Add a variable and a dimension to a given netCDF file in Python

Tags: python, variables, append, netcdf, dimensions

I would like to add a variable with dimensions to a given netCDF file. This is my code example which doesnt work so far.

```
import numpy as np 
import netCDF4 as nc

dataset = nc.Dataset("path", mode ="a") #the dataset in which the variable should be implemented
temp  = dataset.variables["3D_array"] #3D_array has the dimensions lat, lon, time; time with len==unlimited
lat = dataset.variables["latitude"][:]

tmean = (temp[:] * np.cos(np.pi/180. *lat[:, np.newaxis])).mean(axis=(1,2)) 

time = nc.num2date(
    dataset.variables['time'][:],
    units=dataset.variables['time'].units,
    calendar=dataset.variables['time'].calendar,
    only_use_cftime_datetimes=False,
    only_use_python_datetimes=True)

#now creating dimensions and variables

dataset.createDimension("tmean", len(time) #is now equal to 2029)
tmean = dataset.createVariable("tmean", f4 #dtype float32, dimension=("time"))
```

now i get the RuntimeError: NetCDF: String match to name in use.

Since I am new to netCDF i would love some help. Thank you!

Comment: please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - everything including `Traceback (most recent call last):` all the way to (and including) `RuntimeError: ...` - when asking about errors.

Comment: also, your code isn't syntactically correct (missing trailing parens - they seem to have been put into comments) can you make sure this is the exact code you run when you include the traceback? to me it's not clear where the error occurs, and since we don't have your data, it's hard to tell why too.

Comment: Dear Mr. Delgado, it works now. Seems like the error occurred because the dimension and variable were already appended to the netCDF file (Even tho i always got errors...). Anyways, Ill keep your advices in mind for future questions of mine. Thank you!

Comment: ok - glad you figured it out